# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'article_id' for Tagging

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, attributeerror

I am work on a Blogger Rails App from section I3 :

http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#blogger-2

I am getting an error when running the console and attempting to run:

```
a.tags.create name: "tag1"
```

After I run:

```
a = Article.first
```

*tagging.rb* file:

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :articles
end
```

*article.rb* file:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end
```

*tag.rb* file:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :articles, through: :taggings
end
```

I tried adding `has_many :article_id` to the tagging class, raked the `db:migration` and ran it again and it came back with a no method for nill class error.

Where should I define the `article_id`? Does it need to go in to migration file for `CreateTagging`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tagging.rb` file is your join file, and you have `article_id` and `tag_id` defined in there.

I note that you have `belongs_to :articles` ... you should be using the singular ... `belongs_to :article`.  That's likely why you're failing.  Provided you did...

```
generate model Tagging tag:references article:references
```

... as the tutorial suggests, that would have automatically created the two id fields for you in the taggings table.

You can confirm that by examining the `db/schema.rb`

Comment: I checked the Schema file as you suggested:

Comment: I checked the schema.rb file as you suggested.  The taggings does make several references to the articles_id, it was my understanding that it was articles_id that was generated since tag or tagging can belong to multiple articles. My class CreateTaggings < ActiveRecord::Migration also references :articles vs article. I initially tried changing the class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base belongs_to :articles to :article, but I got the same error back after bin/rake db:migration and running (a.tags.create name: "tag1") in the rails console.

Comment: Every `tagging` can belong to only one `tag` and one `article` ... `tagging` is the join record that connects a specific tag to a specific article.  Tags can have many taggings, and articles can have many taggings, but each tagging belongs to only one tag and only one article.  The column names should be `article_id` and `tag_id`

Comment: Thanks. I was able to to rollback the tables for the migrations. It's working now.

Comment: Great I'm glad it's sorted! Feel free to accept my answer if it helped. There's an option to the left of The answer to do that. Cheers